# How can I get values out of a complex array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, nusoap

I am calling a soap function that returns the following array:

`Array ( [FastAddressResult] => Array ( [IsError] => false [ErrorNumber] => 0 [ErrorMessage] => [Results] => Array ( [Address] => Array ( [Id] => 13872147.00 [OrganisationName] => [DepartmentName] => [Line1] => Methley Grove [Line2] => [Line3] => [Line4] => [Line5] => [PostTown] => Leeds [County] => West Yorkshire [Postcode] => LS7 3PA [Mailsort] => 64121 [Barcode] => [IsResidential] => false [IsSmallOrganisation] => false [IsLargeOrganisation] => false [RawData] => [GeographicData] => Array ( [GridEastM] => 0 [GridNorthM] => 0 [Objective2] => false [Transitional] => false [Longitude] => 0 [Latitude] => 0 [WGS84Longitude] => 0 [WGS84Latitude] => 0 ) ) ) )`

I need to exstract the values the following does not seem to work:

```
$this->adressline1 = $result->FastAddressResult->Results->Address->Line1;
```

Comment: *(reference)* http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: `$result->FastAddressResult->Results->Address->Line1;` would be the way to go if it was a series of nested objects, not arrays.

Comment: Why are you treat an array like an object? -> is for accessing object's properties and method i should use the array notation with square bracket

Comment: you could as well mark the right answer

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
$this->adressline1 = $result[ "FastAddressResult" ][ "Results" ][ "Address" ][ "Line1" ];
```

You'd want to use $result->fastAddressResult->etc if $result was an object. Check [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for more info about PHP arrays.

Also, such complex array has certain design smells. You could think of a way to make it simpler and more readable.

Comment: These are the sort of arrays you get back from a SOAP call. Its the XML structure expressed as a set fo recursive hashes.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously someone didn't pay attention in programming class when they covered Arrays...

```
$this->adressline1 = $result['FastAddressResult']['Results']['Address']['Line1'];
```

or convert the array to an stdClass first:

```
$data = (object) $myarray;
```

but you'd have to do that for all the arrays in that too, so no.

Comment: Ok understood , the reason I was treating it like a object is because I was using SOAPCLIENT which for some reason returned a std class . I have recently swapped servers and had to implement NUSOAP instead

Answer (score 1):

Use like this,

array stored in some variable called as $res

```
   echo $res[ "FastAddressResult" ][ "Results" ][ "Address" ][ "Line1" ];
```